# What does ENV=${deploy-qa} mean in bash? How does it evaluate to "qa"?

Tags: bash

```
ENV=${deploy-qa}  
echo $ENV
qa
```

Relatively new to bash and I'm trying to set up a pipeline that switched based off the ending of a string and accidentally stumbled across this. I'm unsure how this actually returns 'qa' though. This is what I was looking to do, but I'd like to understand what's actually happening. I dont understand whats causing the 'deploy-' bit to drop off.

Comment: This is a parameter expansion. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: (the `:` is an optional modifier; its presence or absence determines whether the set-but-empty case is treated like the unset case).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So 'qa' is the default parameter?